# On Windows 7, how to determine network interface being used?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, ip, routing

How can i get the network interface (route) being used for communication on Windows 7?

On Linux we can get this through:

`ip route get 192.168.0.116`

And from Windows 8 to 10, using this PS command:

`Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress  192.168.0.116 | Select-Object interfaceIndex -Last 1`. 
This gives the index of the network interface being used for communication, and through index we can find the actual network interface.

I have tried `tracert`, `pathping` and `route PRINT` but couldn't get the desired result.

Comment: post the errors that received from `route print`, tracert, and pathping.  Maybe that Win7 box needs something along the lines of 'netsh ip reset`.

Answer (score 1):

This might do it:

```
$ifIndex = (Get-NetAdapter -physical | where status -eq 'up').ifIndex
```

Comment: You can have more than one interface with a status of `up`, so this might need a bit of tuning.

Comment: @DougDeden: Usually not physical ones.

Comment: Good point. I've got two physical ones up right now, but the second one is the Npcap Loopback Adapter. So that's an edge case -- most people won't have that.